# Spark : Store data frame into CSV with unicode separator \u2592

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Looking to store spark dataframe into csv, but columns need to be separated with unicode \u2592

considering my dataframe name is myDf

```
myDf.option("header",true)
     .option("encoding", "......")
     .option("delimiter", ".....")
     .csv(s"$path")
```

data should look like

```
my_cd▒my_cd▒flag_cd
00000051▒R▒Y
00000051▒R▒Y
0000007a▒D▒Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution, I was trying delimiter. You can pass any unicode of desire separator as below **option("sep","\u2592")**. It worked for me.

```
myDf.option("header",true)
.option("sep", "\u2592")
.csv(s"$path")
```